# What does "play banks" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "buy the stocks of the banks"?

Goldman analysts said one good way to **play banks** may be in the options market 
because many investors are “overlooking the potential for a rate hike to be a 
positive catalyst for these stocks.” They recommend buying both 6-month and 
12-month calls on financials. Buying calls is a way to gain exposure to a stock 
without owning it out right and it gives the investor the right to buy a 
security at a set price and time.

source: www.marketwatch.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play in this context  means "trade" that is, buy and sell banks stocks possibly in a short time because you are expecting a short term increase in the bank stocks  prices.

***[Play](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/play):***

> - to exploit or trade in (an investment, business opportunity, stock, etc.).

(Dictionary.com)

***[Play](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/play.asp)***:

> - A slang term that describes the positive aspects of an investment decision. A play in investing is the reason why an investor made his or her decision.
> - "Playing the stock market" is a phrase used by beginner investors signifying that they have gained access, simulated or real, to the ups and downs of the stock market.

(Investopedia)